# How do I load Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot

I have downloaded the ISO file and unloaded it and burnt to a DVD but I cant get the computer to boot using the DVD. I have in the past been able to install a older copy of Ubuntu as it had a install application file on the DVD to start the install. Is there a secret way to start the install. My proposed install is to go along side a present copy of Win10
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you verify the .iso? Did you *write* the .iso as a complete image with your DVD authoring software? Did you opt to boot to optical media during your computer's boot process?

Comment: You might need to change boot order in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

See here for general instructions:

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Your computer might not try to boot from DVD by default. Some PCs have a key combination that will open a boot menu to select what device to boot from (hard disk, DVD, USB):

https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/b/boot_menu.htm

Try F10 or F12 or F2 or Esc.

If that doesn't work, go to the BIOS and temporarily change the boot order to try booting from DVD first. What key you need to use to get to the BIOS depends on your PC; it might be any of Esc, F8, F2.